# How can i float inbox right without moving options icon

Tags: html, css

I know the title wasn't very good but in my topnav I have inbox and a options with 3 vertical dots but when I float both of them to the right (`float:right;`) the inbox is at the end which I don't want, I want the inbox to be to the left of the options. Here is the code

```
  .notification {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 26px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.notification:hover {
  background: red;
}

.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}



<div id="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="home">Home</a>
    <a id="font2" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#" class="notification">
  <span>Inbox</span>
  <span class="badge">1</span>
</a>
    <button id="options" style="float:right;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="27" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M9.5 13a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0z"/>
</svg></button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float ordering occurs simply because your Inbox appears first in the code. You tell it to float right, and it does. You then tell your Button to float right, and it then floats right, but your Inbox is already on the far right, so it appears to the left of it.

The simplest solution might be to rearrange the order in which the Inbox and Button appear in the HTML code. So, put the Button first, then it will float right first.
The snippet below uses the float method with the HTML element reordered:

```css
.notification {
  float: right;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 26px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.notification:hover {
  background: red;
}

.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#options {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="home">Home</a>
  <a id="font2" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
  <button id="options"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="27" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M9.5 13a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0z"/>
</svg></button>

  <a href="#" class="notification">
    <span>Inbox</span>
    <span class="badge">1</span>
  </a>
</div>
```